# Infinite lattice with every totally ordered set finite

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, lattice-orders

Construct a lattice L such that L is infinite but every totally ordered subset of L is finite? I really don't know how to proceed because i don't see how every totally ordered set would be finite since every element would approach a maximal element and this would force an infinite chain? I am not very clear with my thoughts and am pretty confused. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this infinite lattice (where for all `n`, `B < n < T`) the totally ordered subsets have 1, 2 or 3 elements.

```
         T

1  2  3  4  5 ...

         B
```

Comment: Are B and T the maximal and minimal elements?

Comment: @Sj2704 It's apparently the other way around: $T$ for top, which is maximal, moreover, the maximum; $B$ for bottom, which is minimal and moreover, minimum. But I suppose you got that and just wrote it in the wrong order.

Comment: @Sj2704 I'm not sure what you mean by "wrong order". I put the minimum element B for Bottom at the bottom of the Hasse diagram. In any case I think you understand my example. You can accept the answer (check mark) if it satisfies you.